# Cut the image beyond the div width

Tags: css

I have a SVG in my page & i have aligned it to the right so that its middle is center to the edge of the div within which it is present. Similar to the pic below

[image]

I want to however hide the portion of image that is beyond the border of the container.

Like this
[image]

How do I achieve this?
Code to the page which shows the current status is below (this is not my actual page but this explains the issue I am having). SO does not allow the codepen.io link to be added directly, hence added this way.

```
[codepen] (https://codepen.io/moyscode/pen/VwQYrry)
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0 1rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 2rem;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.baby {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(calc(50% - 1rem), -50%);
  width: 30vmin;
  height: 30vmin;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='header'>
    <h3> Header</h3>
  </div>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 384 512" width="100" title="baby" class='baby'>
  <path d="M192 160c44.2 0 80-35.8 80-80S236.2 0 192 0s-80 35.8-80 80 35.8 80 80 80zm-53.4 248.8l25.6-32-61.5-51.2L56.8 383c-11.4 14.2-11.7 34.4-.8 49l48 64c7.9 10.5 19.9 16 32 16 8.3 0 16.8-2.6 24-8 17.7-13.2 21.2-38.3 8-56l-29.4-39.2zm142.7-83.2l-61.5 51.2 25.6 32L216 448c-13.2 17.7-9.7 42.8 8 56 7.2 5.4 15.6 8 24 8 12.2 0 24.2-5.5 32-16l48-64c10.9-14.6 10.6-34.8-.8-49l-45.9-57.4zM376.7 145c-12.7-18.1-37.6-22.4-55.7-9.8l-40.6 28.5c-52.7 37-124.2 37-176.8 0L63 135.3C44.9 122.6 20 127 7.3 145-5.4 163.1-1 188 17 200.7l40.6 28.5c17 11.9 35.4 20.9 54.4 27.9V288h160v-30.8c19-7 37.4-16 54.4-27.9l40.6-28.5c18.1-12.8 22.4-37.7 9.7-55.8z" />     
  </svg>
  <div class='Content'>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
  </div>

  <div class='Footer'>
    <h3> Footer</h3>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I imagine the downvote was due the code not being included in the question, which is generally a requirement. (There's even a warning "Links to codepen.io must be accompanied by code.", that you appear to have intentionally disabled by wrapping the link in a code block)

Comment: @DBS What does "Links to codepen.io must be accompanied by code." warning even mean? We created a codepen.io project to share the code, then why do we have to include it here? It did not make sense to me. Also, it is so much easier to create a page in codepen instead of here.

Comment: It means that if you include a link to codepen, it is expected that that code is also included in the question (Otherwise any changes to the external page may cause questions to be incomplete for future readers) Also, you can use the "Snippet" tool in the editor to have basically the same experience as codepen in your question here (It looks like a page icon containing `<>`, to the right of the image tool)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `position: fixed` which will place the SVG outside of the element with the `.container` class.

`position: fixed` will tell the browser that the element is placed relative to the window viewport; `position: absolute` will tell the element that any positioning provided will be relative to this element's parent.

**Solution:**
Use `position: absolute` on the SVG and `overflow: hidden` on the `.container` class.

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='header'>
    <h3> Header</h3>
  </div>
  
  <svg viewBox="0 0 384 512" width="100" title="baby" class='baby'>
    <path d="M192 160c44.2 0 80-35.8 80-80S236.2 0 192 0s-80 35.8-80 80 35.8 80 80 80zm-53.4 248.8l25.6-32-61.5-51.2L56.8 383c-11.4 14.2-11.7 34.4-.8 49l48 64c7.9 10.5 19.9 16 32 16 8.3 0 16.8-2.6 24-8 17.7-13.2 21.2-38.3 8-56l-29.4-39.2zm142.7-83.2l-61.5 51.2 25.6 32L216 448c-13.2 17.7-9.7 42.8 8 56 7.2 5.4 15.6 8 24 8 12.2 0 24.2-5.5 32-16l48-64c10.9-14.6 10.6-34.8-.8-49l-45.9-57.4zM376.7 145c-12.7-18.1-37.6-22.4-55.7-9.8l-40.6 28.5c-52.7 37-124.2 37-176.8 0L63 135.3C44.9 122.6 20 127 7.3 145-5.4 163.1-1 188 17 200.7l40.6 28.5c17 11.9 35.4 20.9 54.4 27.9V288h160v-30.8c19-7 37.4-16 54.4-27.9l40.6-28.5c18.1-12.8 22.4-37.7 9.7-55.8z" />
  </svg>
  
  <div class='Content'>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
  </div>

  <div class='Footer'>
    <h3> Footer</h3>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  margin: 0 1rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container{
  margin: 0 2rem;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden; // this ensure that any overflow shouldn't be visible
}

.baby {
  position: absolute; // this has to be absolute instead of fixed
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(calc(50% - 1rem), -50%);
  width: 30vmin;
  height: 30vmin;
}
```

**Update for using `position: fixed`:**

In the case that you want the image to be fixed, you could wrap it in a container and give the container the existing SVG styles, then give that container `position: fixed` and `overflow: hidden`, and the SVG inside it can be moved with `position: absolute`. In this case, you have to adjust the spacing so that the margins of the containers are equal.

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='header'>
    <h3> Header</h3>
  </div>

  <div class='baby'>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 384 512" width="100" title="baby">
      <path d="M192 160c44.2 0 80-35.8 80-80S236.2 0 192 0s-80 35.8-80 80 35.8 80 80 80zm-53.4 248.8l25.6-32-61.5-51.2L56.8 383c-11.4 14.2-11.7 34.4-.8 49l48 64c7.9 10.5 19.9 16 32 16 8.3 0 16.8-2.6 24-8 17.7-13.2 21.2-38.3 8-56l-29.4-39.2zm142.7-83.2l-61.5 51.2 25.6 32L216 448c-13.2 17.7-9.7 42.8 8 56 7.2 5.4 15.6 8 24 8 12.2 0 24.2-5.5 32-16l48-64c10.9-14.6 10.6-34.8-.8-49l-45.9-57.4zM376.7 145c-12.7-18.1-37.6-22.4-55.7-9.8l-40.6 28.5c-52.7 37-124.2 37-176.8 0L63 135.3C44.9 122.6 20 127 7.3 145-5.4 163.1-1 188 17 200.7l40.6 28.5c17 11.9 35.4 20.9 54.4 27.9V288h160v-30.8c19-7 37.4-16 54.4-27.9l40.6-28.5c18.1-12.8 22.4-37.7 9.7-55.8z" />
    </svg>
  </div>

  <div class='Content'>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
    <h3> Thing</h3>
  </div>

  <div class='Footer'>
    <h3> Footer</h3>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  margin: 0 1rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container{
  margin: 0 2rem;
  position : relative;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.baby {
  position: fixed;
  right: 3rem;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 136px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.baby svg {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

Comment: James, I want the picture to stay there even when I scroll the page up & down. If I use `position: absolute;` , I think that is not possible.

Comment: Ah I didn't get that. I've added an update to my answer

Comment: James, Thanks. You answer works on the codepen.io sample code as is. In my actual project however I had to tweak it a little bit. May be because I have no height & width of the `baby` but it i on the `svg` (in my case `img`) element. Thanks anyway. Up-voted & accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) in css to put your image beyond the body but in front of your container